# How to programmatically download mhtml file of a webpage in Android

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs, mhtml

I'm using `chrome-custom-tabs` to load the webpages in my Android app. It provides an option to download the page. Is there a way I can pre-download the mhtml files and load them in the  `chrome-custom-tabs` for offline use rather than downloading them via  `chrome-custom-tabs`?